# Mysql multiple join with optional value in ON clause

Tags: mysql, left-join

Ok, First see this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbc3a/2

Here the query return the count and all, but what i want is that it selects a forum and return the count of topics and post in it then next forum and all topics and post counts from it and so on with forums name, url and desc. I thought doing this in one query instead of many queries in loop would be better. I don't know what i am doing with that mysql query though, i am not very good with mysql and i haven't sleep for so long. Thanks for help.

EDIT:

This is what i expect to see from the data provided in te fiddle above^

```
| FORUMNAME | FORUMURL |    FORUMDESC | FORUMTIME | TOPICCOUNT | POSTCOUNT |
|   Forum 1 |  Forum-1 | Forum 1 Desc | 343243243 |          1 |         1 |
|   Forum 2 |  Forum-2 | Forum 2 Desc | 343243243 |          0 |         0 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT f.Name      ForumName,  
       f.Url       ForumUrl, 
       f.Desc      ForumDesc, 
       f.Time      ForumTime,
       COUNT(DISTINCT t.ID) TopicCount, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT p.ID) PostCount 
  FROM name_forums f
  LEFT JOIN name_topics t ON t.ForumId = f.ID
  LEFT JOIN name_posts p  ON p.TopicId = t.ID
 WHERE f.CategoryId = 1 
 GROUP BY f.name, f.url, f.desc
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcfc8e/4)** demo

Comment: hmm! i think i spoke too soon, its returning the TopicCount and PostCount always same no matter whatever the original number is. For Example in a forum i have 1 topics and 2 post in that topic. It returns the Post count "2" just fine but Topic count is "2" also. Thats a problem. Have any other ideas? Here a demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcfc8e/1

Comment: @Prashank Updated the answer and sqlfiddle. Chaining outer joins might be tricky. In that particular case the second left join produce additional rows for first one. To overcome this you need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT column)`.